# do I need overvoltage protection with 4.8V NI-MH pack?

Tags: protection, nimh

I plan to run an avr like attiny + led strip with 5V supply.
The whole thing can draw up to 15A at 5V.
To avoid heating problem stepdown and other regulator problem, I've choosen a pack of 4 * 1.2V NiMH battery wich can discharge up to 10C.

The problem is that NiMh after a full charge can be at 1.4V instead of 1.2v. So I will have 5.6V in my system wich is very near the limit for working without problems (reading datasheets).

Do you think I should use a protection for overvoltage pic? 
which one could fit as I need to pass 15A through it.

thx

Comment: Power the AVR via an LDO and the LED strip directly, if it can take 5.6V.

Answer (score 2):

If just you use this circuit with NiMH batteries as discribed a overvoltage protection is not needed. But it could come in handy when there is the possibility to use primary cells that might have a voltage of 1.5 V or another voltage source.

A low dropout voltage regulator for the controller supply would be a simple solution. Depending on the current drawn by your controller a series resistor and/or diode might also help.